# Docker on Mac: Can't view ports

Tags: docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

I'm running boot2docker on Yosemite. I have no trouble creating containers and using them in boot2docker. I also can successfully connect via http to the docker daemon running in boot2docker's vm. However, when I create a container with Revel and start Revel up, I cannot connect to Revel's port 9000 from my browser.

I was following this approach: http://www.medding.me/blog/2014/09/06/setting-up-a-docker-environment-for-golang-development-part-1/

Here's the running Revel server:

```
INFO  2015/05/07 20:19:00 revel.go:329: Loaded module static
INFO  2015/05/07 20:19:00 revel.go:329: Loaded module testrunner
INFO  2015/05/07 20:19:00 revel.go:206: Initialized Revel v0.12.0 (2015-03-25) for >= go1.3
INFO  2015/05/07 20:19:00 run.go:57: Running revel3 (alexed1/revel3) in dev mode
INFO  2015/05/07 20:19:00 harness.go:165: Listening on :9000
```

When I connect to 192.168.59.103:9000 with a browser, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I've tried a couple of different things:

1. The dockerfile has EXPOSE(9000) in it;
2. The VirtualBox client has been configured this way:
   http://screencast.com/t/KiRdimWVnwqS in accordance with the direction of http://odewahn.github.io/docker-jumpstart/boot2docker.html. I've tried using both localhost and 127.0.0.1 for the host value.

As you can see, no port information shows up on the running container:

[image]

Comment: How are you calling `docker run`? It sounds like you are not forwarding port 9000 from the inside of your container to the outside something like `docker run -p 40001:9000 the/image/name` ? Also can you include the dockerfile? And perhaps the output of `docker inspect CONTAINER-ID-HERE`

Comment: Use boot2docker ssh, and enter to the shell of boot2docker and then use telnet for example to see if it is expose 9000 port.  telnet localhost 9000. If it works it means that you have some trouble with port forwarding to the local system from boot2docker vm.

Comment: @jm_____ was correct. it was as simple as adding the port forwarding to the docker run command. jm, if you want to add that as an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXPOSE` is **not** for "exposing" ports to the host, it's for interconnecting containers, see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/).

As mentioned from **jm_____** you have to forward the port of the container to your `boot2docker` host :

```
docker run -p 40001:9000 the/image/name
```

and then access it with:

```
open http://192.168.59.103:40001
```

or by finding the port with `docker ps` as you tried already.

*PS: There's no `PORT` in a `Dockerfile`, but you can specify this in a `docker-compose.yml` file.*

Comment: why doesn't this allow you to access localhost:40001? Why do you still need the IP of the docker machine if the port is mapped?

Comment: ahhhhhh I guess what is happening is that on the Mac the host is not localhost; it’s the linux VM. so we have a container inside of a host (boot2docker) on a host (mac)

So now my question is whether I can map http://192.168.59.103:40001 to localhost:40001?

Comment: You can do this in the VirtualBox GUI under `Network > Port-forwarding` or via CLI.